# The class Form1 can be designed, but is not the first class in the file[...]

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm a newbie on vb.net, and I was in progress with my first application... and found some example code in the msdn so I just replaced my `Form1.vb` file content with the content from the MSDN. When I roll back the changes, and tried to compile my old code then hundreds of errors appeared, and when I switch to the `Form1[Design]` tab I see this:

> The class Form1 can be designed, but is not the first class in the
>   file. Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the
>   file. Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file
>   and try loading the designer again.

I'm really new on vb.net and the visual studio itself, and I dont know what to do in this case, is my work destroyed or what?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

That's because you added some class or other code above the class definition in form1.vb. Remove that.

Comment: `Form1.vb` file content is my old code, which worked properly before.

Comment: remove any class declarations or any other code before `Public class Form1`

Comment: There are only `Imports System.Net` and `Imports System.IO` before the `Public class Form1`.

Comment: then try rebuilding the entire solution solution, and click reload the designer

Comment: I do : `Build -> Rebuild WindowsApplication1` and it is still throwing up an errors, also I don't see any button called `Reload the designer`.

Comment: I have noticed that I have two classes - `Form1.vb` and `Form1.Designer.vb` if theres a connection..

Comment: those are not classes, those are files. Make sure they both contain parts of the same partial class.

Comment: Also, when I remove the `Form1.vb` file content, the project compiles successfully, but I cant do nothing - buttons etc. doesnt works. Here is the `Form1.vb` file content: http://pastebin.com/VZ5DFbsZ and here is the `Form1.Designer.vb` http://pastebin.com/0ssiKqdi

Comment: your code is wrong: `Public Class News_ann` you cannot have that. If you want to change the form name do it in the designer, or rename the file in the solution explorer. Otherwise change it back to `Public Class Form1`

Comment: @HighCore I was 100% sure it was compiling with the `Public Class News_ann` before... Anyway, sorry for being such a newbie. Thank you for your great help and patience!

Comment: Yeah, worked I had added constant class, now I moved it down..But why it shows error!!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is editing both Form1.vb and Form1.Designer.vb and placing at the beginning of both files: `Namespace Whatever` and at the end of both files: `End Namespace`. The "Whatever" can be any name not already used in the program (or the name of an existing Namespace that you're already using).

Answer (score 0):

You added another class in your form and that is the reason of the error. I had ran into same issue. I had added another class in the form and that caused this error. To resolve,  I moved the new class to a module(created new module) and then access the class in the required form.

Answer (score 0):

Had a student that renamed the public class at the top of his code and got this error. We changed it back to form1 and then all the errors went away.